# Next.js Architecture

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, architecture, next.js

I am looking for some Next.js Architecture advise please

I am in the middle of migrating a very large express NodeJS app which has a custom SSR setup over to a Next.js setup.

For the current NodeJS site I have:

- A bunch of routes (which hook up controllers / apis, do fancy redirections etc)
- Have a ton of middlewares
- Ton of logic in a bunch of express controllers (these controllers do things like API calls, transforming data, validation and the SSR of some React components to form the application)
- Most of the time the NodeJS server calls other Microservice APIs (on the same VPC) to fetch data within these controllers (eg: search api, auth api, location api etc - which are all seperate REST api servers) **Note:** when it fetches from these APIs its done so on an internal api address only
- The React Website itself calls the same NodeJS server to fetch data via client side JS when there is a route change `eg:` The frontend URL would be: `www.mywebsite.com.au`
  And any api call done from the frontend is done with route: `www.mywebsite.com.au/api/*`

Based on all the docs i have read so far, I figure the best setup is:

1. To keep my existing express setup for routes / middlewares (for which I have a ton of) this includes the `/api/*` ones
2. Migrate controller fetching logic to the publically accessible express apis `/api/*` (which I kind of already have but need to clean up)
3. For the existing express controller routes, route these to Next.js instead and use `nextApp.render` to specific next pages
4. Use `getInitialProps` in the Next.js pages to fetch data from those apis I mentioned in 2.
5. Also add the old prop transform logic that was in the express controllers to `getInitialProps`

This is so that the server and client share the same logic of whats in `getInitialProps` - and this will make the architecture clean and give me the ability to have smooth transition to use `Link`.

The thing im struggling with it is step 4.

It means now on SSR of a page request it needs to call out to the public api (`www.mywebsite.com.au/api/*`) on `getInitialProps` to fetch its data.

To me seems like a performance overhead to do this as it requires a network hop to public domain `mywebsite.com.au` to fetch data it could have got locally on that same request (by calling `localhost:3000/api/*` for instance)

Any advise on how to avoid the network hop outside for server render?
Can I detect if its a server render and then use an internal URL (eg: use `localhost:3000/api/*` on the request to the same web server) or is that not best practices when using Next.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server needs to call out to itself to fetch its data, alot of the overhead involved with fetching data is around the delay (I.E Between the client and nearest datacenter) this will be less of a concern when its (datacenter -> datacenter).

If performance is still an issue, your next best bet will be to do SSR caching, of which there are many different methods alot you can find in a quick google search however it will depend on your hosting/setup.

Comment: It is datacenter -> datacenter (in fact its fetching data from the same server - the server has api routes) - So you dont advise using an internal api URL (to avoid the network hop to the DMZ accessible access) for SSR only and change to public domain on client side requests?

Comment: Not following, but whether there is or isn't delay is a non-issue, NextJS offers numerous escape hatches for every feature it provides, if you don't want SSR you can turn it off, if you want SSR but not for a request that will take a long time you can SSR half the page, and then send request for data on client. You can even disable SSR on a per-component basis (see next dynamic). You can even stream SSR to the page/do advanced caching using react-esi or another alternative.

getInitialProps is optional and how you use/implement it is up to you.

Comment: What do you mean `getInitialProps` is optional - How else do you make an isomorphic app without it ?

Comment: You can detect if its the server, and change the logic.
`typeof window === "undefined"` will tell you its the server note `undefined` is purposely a string here you can put this in getInitialProps and fetch the data from another source

Comment: Yeah i can do that - just feels like it may not be "best practice" to do that? Its not another data source, its the same source just using an internal URL on server side as it doesnt need to do a network hop out

Comment: Ill mark this as the answer but still keen to hear if there is any other suggestions - feels like the app goes unnecessarily outside the network when the data can be fetched from the same server

Answer (score 0):

I treat `listing-page.jsx` and handler for `api/listing` route to be the same. You may need to write 2 small functions to extract the parameters passed into the request and pass it down to your service module function like `ListingService.getSingleListisng(id)`